# express.js wildcard routing issue

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I looked up online and found a solution but it's not working. I can't figure out why. Here is my code;

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data) {
        res.write(data);
        res.end('');
    })
});
```

This one works as intended. But If I add wildcard route as,

```
app.get('/:randomEndPoint', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.randomEndPoint);
    fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data) {
        res.write(data);
        res.end('');
    })
});
```

I can log endpoint correctly on console. However, res.write command isn't working. This is the error message;

```
_http_outgoing.js:595 throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument', ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must 
be one of type string or Buffer. Received type undefined 
at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:595:11) at ServerResponse.write 
(_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This error states that `data` is not a string or buffer in `res.write(data);`. Try `console.log(data)` before write and see what you get.

Comment: Yes, received type seems undefined, but how its working on first part? It's just same code.

Comment: In this case you could use `fs. readFileSync` your response is dependent on the file read.

Comment: @neiloth are both routes in the same file?

Comment: @fedesc Yes, is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it doesn't make any sense to me, using readFileSync worked.

```
const index = fs.readFileSync('./dist/index.html', 'utf8');

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.write(index);
    res.end('');
});
```